# Graphics.FillRectangle() didn't work

Tags: c#

```
Graphics gp = Graphics.FromHwnd(p2pPic.Handle);

SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(Color.DodgerBlue);

lock (gpPalette)
{
     gpP.FillRectangle(sb, aRectangle);
}
```

`p2pPic` is a `PictureBox` object in c#;
these are the main code ,and code does run, but did not take any effect who can tell me why?

Comment: The code you've posted is minimal and contains mistakes. Could you post a more complete snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends where you have placed this code. PictureBox would eventually do its own painting.

Comment: when p2pPic.Handle can be called, i think PictureBox has do its own painting already, am i right? plz help me

Comment: Derive from `PictureBox` and override `OnPaint` method.